# Parameterizing queries by adding a delimiter

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, parameters, sql-injection

Asumming that all parameters are strings and  I am running all parameters through this function (I am forbidding the "|" character on my site)

```
public String EscapeParameter(String Param)
{
  return "|" + param.replace("|", "") + "|"  
}
```

Is something like this a safe way to parameterize queries. At this point  I know for certain that all params start with "|" and end with "|" so can I just walk through the string and parameterize the query regardless of how it was built originally?

```
public String DynamicParameterizeQuery(String sql)
{
    int stringSize = sql.length();
    StringBuilder paraValueBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    Boolean inParam = false;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < stringSize; i++)
    {
        Character currentChar = sql.charAt(i);
        if(currentChar == '|' && inParam == false)
        {
            inParam = true;
        }
        else if(currentChar == '|' && inParam == true)
        {
            inParam = false;
            paramMap.put(":" + i*1000, paraValueBuilder.toString());
            sb.append(":" + i*1000 + " ");
            paraValueBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        }
        else
        {
            sb.append(currentChar);
        }
    }
    getRows(sql, paramMap);
}


/**
 * Gets a list of objects <T> from the database.
 *
 * @param <T> object type to be returned
 * @param sql query to execute
 * @param objectParameters query parameter values
 * @param targetClass target class that will be returned. <T>
 * @return A list of the specified objects.
 */
public <T> List<T> getRows(String sql, Object objectParameters, Class<T> targetClass) {
    RowMapper<T> rowMapper = new BeanPropertyRowMapper<T>(targetClass);
    return getRows(sql, objectParameters, rowMapper);
}
```

is this a safe way to prevent SQL Injection?

Comment: It's not clear why you need to do this when you could use proper SQL parameters?

Comment: this example does use proper SQL Parameters, it just adds them after the fact?

Comment: Can you show an example of using your function? What would the SQL query look like? Also, I'm not familiar with "@" tokens as parameter placeholders, I'm accustomed to simple `?` placeholders. Also, I've never seen a version of `executeQuery()` that takes a Map object. What are you using?

Comment: i'm talking about wrapping parameters a user puts in with some kind of a delimiter, a bar for example
public String EscapeParameter(String Param)
{
   return "|" + param.replace("|", "") + "|"  
}

and then recreating a parameterized query

Comment: I've updated the question, it's GenericJdbcDaoSupport, (it's built into) Spring

Answer (score 0):

I would not use this method.

It's not clear what this is intended to solve. I guess you are dedicated to the idea that you need to concatenate dynamic values into your SQL queries, to the point where you'd rather do that and then write an elaborate Java method to extract the values back out to use them as proper parameters.

And you have chosen "|" as a delimiter character, which means your site must prohibit any content that includes that character. Good luck explaining that limitation to your product manager, or to users.

Why not just use query parameters directly?

- Parameters are already known as a safe and reliable solution.
- Parameters are easiest and less error-prone.
- Parameters do not require a new Java method to un-concatenate the string.
- Parameters have no limitation on what characters can appear in the values. By the way, how would your method handle binary data?

There's something to be said for using the standard solution that everyone already knows is safe. During a code review, you could save at least 30 minutes by *not* having to explain your DynamicParameterizeQuery() method and why it's safe and why your site can't support "|" characters.

[image]

Comment: Code Review? this app was written 20 years go, There are over 3000 Queries, and at least 30 or 40 thousand parameters, probably more. Hand rewriting each query is out of the question.

so i'm left with trying to come up with the next best thing. What is the second most secure way to query basicall

Comment: Old versions of Apache Commons Lang like 2.0 have `StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql()` but it's deprecated in current versions. Don't you have to rewrite each query anyway, whether you use a third-party string escape method, or your own method, or parameters?